# how to clone an element when choosing a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, clone

I have a page with elements

```
<div class="sample-area-wrapper border-bottom-block">
    <div class="samples-items-wrapper">
        <div class="sample-item-wrapper">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Dv_BuildingBedPage::images/image1.png'); ?>" />
            <div class="pretty p-default">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <div class="state">
                    <label></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sample-item-wrapper">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Dv_BuildingBedPage::images/image1.png'); ?>" />
            <div class="pretty p-default">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <div class="state">
                    <label></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="selected-items"></div>
```

Help implement the functionality. if selected,

```
<input type="checkbox" />
```

copy the `sample-item-wrapper` entire block and add it to

`selected-items`

suitable implementation on knockout and jquery

I tried this but it failed. I was looking for many more other ways that I tried to integrate with my code, but nothing worked

```
<div class="selected">

</div>

<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function ($) {
        'use strict';
        $(":checkbox").change(function() {
            var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { return $(this).next().html(); }).get();
            $(".selected").html(arr.join(', '));
        });

        function ToggleBGColour(item) {
            var td = $(item).parent();
            if (td.is('.rowSelected'))
                td.removeClass("rowSelected");
            else
                td.addClass("rowSelected");
        }

    });
</script>
```

this work but add the wrong element to block 
[image]

[image]

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: *"how to clone"* - did you try `.clone()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clone HTML DIV with jQuery on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28853703/clone-html-div-with-jquery-on-select)

Comment: If it's selecting the wrong element, then you need to change the selector to the correct element: in `$(this).next().html()`, `this` is the checkbox, so you need `$(this).closest(".sample-item-wrapper").html()` - not sure that's *actually* what you want, but that's what you've said "*whole of sample-item-wrapper*"

Comment: @freedomn-m
It works, thank you very much, can you fill out the answer so that I choose it as the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `closest`method to get the content and simply use `.html` to append the content to the selected section.

You can use `clone` method to get the whole element.

**EDIT**

Here you can add some identifier (e.g. is) to the `div` to identify and remove the selected items from the bottom section.

As there is no identifier here in your case, I have used image URL to uniquely identify and remove element on uncheck event of the checkbox.

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked") == true){
                $(".selected-items").append(($(this).closest(".sample-item-wrapper").clone()))
            }
            else if($(this).prop("checked") == false){
                var selected_item = $(this).closest(".sample-item-wrapper").attr('data-sample-id');
$("div.selected-items div[data-sample-id='"+selected_item+"']").remove()
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sample-area-wrapper border-bottom-block">
    <div class="samples-items-wrapper">
        <div class="sample-item-wrapper" data-sample-id="sample-1">
            <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/237/200/300.jpg" />
            <div class="pretty p-default">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <div class="state">
                    <label></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sample-item-wrapper" data-sample-id="sample-2">
            <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/866/200/300.jpg" />
            <div class="pretty p-default">
                <input type="checkbox" />
                <div class="state">
                    <label></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="selected-items"></div>
```

Comment: This adds content, not the entire block. and replaces the contents with another if you select another block

Comment: So, you need to keep adding elements if multiple checkboxes checked? What if I uncheck element?

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can use `append` to append the selected items.

Comment: You have an error if you select more than one item, and then uncheck one of them, then all will be lost. Not sure how to solve this?

Comment: Yes. I am aware of it. How do you want to handle it? I thought you will handle it as per your requirement.

Comment: I have updated my answer and added alert to handle uncheck. I can help you if you tell me what should happen on uncheck.

Comment: When unchecking, the same element as the one unchecked should disappear

Comment: Only the one that was unchecked should disappear

Comment: I am checking your HTML. There are 2 `sample-item-wrapper` divs. There is no difference between them. Do you have any identifiers? ID or something. Os is your image unique?

Comment: I see that your method works, but it does not work for me, tell me, mb I forgot to add something?
https://imgur.com/a/5JfftAH

Comment: Ok, I add data-sample-id for each element, but this does not work. This does not remove the item but adds a new one if I double-checked.
https://imgur.com/a/tMAlchW

Comment: My bad. Previous 2 lines were incorrect. Change it to `var selected_item = $(this).closest(".sample-item-wrapper").attr('data-sample-id');
$("div.selected-items div[data-sample-id='"+selected_item+"']").remove()`

I have updated the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried this and it works but adds the wrong element:
>
> ```
> var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { return $(this).next().html(); }).get();
> ```

If it's selecting the wrong element, then you need to change the selector to the correct element: in `$(this).next().html()`, `this` is the checkbox, so to get the "whole of sample-item-wrapper", you need:

```
 $(this).closest(".sample-item-wrapper").html()
```

---

To take the whole of sample-item-wrapper (not just its content)

```
$(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
    $(".selected").append($(this).closest(".sample-item-wrapper").clone());
});
```

without the `.clone` it will *move* existing elements.

Comment: Tell me something else, now my elements do not have a wrapper, see the last screenshot.
Is there any way to add them along with sample-item-wrapper?

Comment: You're using `.html()` which takes the *content* of that element - use `.clone()` instead which will give you an object.

Comment: [object Object]
:)

Comment: To pre-empt your next question, the tickboxes on the clones/copies don't work as you're using direct events, change to event delegation:  `$(document).on("change", ":checkbox", function() ...` (or remove the checkboxes when you clone them so you only have one set of "controls")

Comment: `[object Object]` shows you're using `alert()` - don't use `alert()`, use `console.log()` and look in the console.  Also, don't use `.html(object)`, use `.append(object)` (as already in the answer, it's possible you only changed .html() to .clone() without reading the full answer)

Comment: I did not use it

Comment: I used
`
        $(":checkbox").change(function() {
            var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { return $(this).closest(".sample-item-wrapper").clone(); }).get();
            $(".selected").html(arr.join(''));
        });
`

Comment: Ah, you didn't read what I put in the answer.  You can't just replace `.html` with `.clone`, as stated in the updated answer.